Prove that if $n$ is composite, there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ st $n | ab$ and $n \nmid a$ and $n \nmid b$
Gave my shot at a proof of the above statement. It goes like this:
Proof: Let $n$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetics, we express it as a sequence of primes $n=p_1,^{\alpha_1} \cdot \cdot \cdot p_i^{\alpha_i} \cdot \cdot \cdot p_s^{\alpha_s}$ such that  $\forall_i  \{ \alpha_i \geq 1\}  \land s \geq 1 $.
Then if $n | ab$ we can say $\exists c \in \mathbb{Z}$ st $nc = ab$. Let, $a = p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdot \cdot \cdot p_j^{\alpha_j} $ and $b =  p_{j+1}^{\alpha_{j+1}} \cdot \cdot \cdot p_s^{\alpha_s} \cdot \cdot \cdot p_k^{k}$. It is clear that $n \nmid b$ and $n \nmid a$.
Im not sure if this cover all cases, any comments are appreciated as I am getting on proves after a long time.


What's $j$? 2. What happens if $s = 1$, say $n = 8 = 2^3$?


$j$ would be $1 < j < k$ but, I now see the problem. If $s=1$ then the "slice" I was trying to remove would not be remove but stay in $a$, then $b=1$ and $n=a$ when the idea is that if $a < n$ and $b < n$ then necessarily $n \nmid a$ and $n \nmid b$
